# How do I create a MEF compatible component with resources?

Tags: silverlight, mef, resourcedictionary

This seems like such a simple requirement but I'm hitting my head against a wall!

I've got an existing SL4 application, which I'm trying to add in modules using MEF.  I've created my loading architecture and can load the page from my referenced XAP file.

I want to have resources, in this case the ViewModelLocator, described within a resource dictionary associated with my loaded in XAP.  I have achieved this by exporting the ResourceDictionary and importing it before loading the page and this is working correctly.

However, this does not give me design time support for any resources I place into the resource dictionary.  How do I get blendability/design time support for these resources?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/09/best-practices-for-themes-in-modular.html If you have problems, be sure to check out the comments at the bottom of the article as well.

Comment: The article refers to having support in Blend (not VS) for styles that basically exist in the core silverlight application.  This is more for delay loading the plugins.  I am trying to use a plugin architecture where the individual plugins have their own styles and not just use themes from the core application.  The only way I can see to support this is to copy and paste the styles into the top of each XAML file, or just put up with the lack of blendability and many errors that get displayed while developing.